# String Search search a Phrase in a line in any order

Tags: java, python, string, search, full-text-search

I am trying to implement a phrase search with match of words in any order.
However any extra words added should say not matched.

For example

```
"i want pizza"
```

It should match the following in any case.

```
"want i pizza"
"i want pizza"
"pizza want i"
```

But it should not match Any words other than the ones in search string.

It should not match :

```
"i want a pizza on monday"
```

Can anyone guide me with this implementation in any JAVA, C# or Python.

Currently i am using MYSQL Full Text Search. But need to implement this solution to avoid mistakes of full text search. If there is any way to do this directly with FULL TEXT Search of MYSQL Please suggest

Comment: Are you trying to do that on the database or in code? When in code you could try to split the text and your search phrase into words, create a cardinality map or set (if cardinality doesn't matter) out of both and compare them.

Comment: should it match Yoda's `pizza i want` too?

Comment: I am trying to do it in MYSQL as well as code for different purposes

Answer (score 1):

In java something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   String str = "i want pizza";
   List<String> list = Arrays.asList("want i pizza", "i want pizza", "pizza want i","i want a pizza on monday");
   list.stream()
           .filter(s->Arrays.asList(str.split(" ")).containsAll(Arrays.asList(s.split(" "))))
           .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it in python code is using split and comparison .

```
A =  "i want pizza"
V = ["want i pizza", "i want pizza", "pizza want i", "i want a pizza on monday"]

A = sorted(A.split())

match = [i for i in V if A == sorted(i.split())]
print match
```

**Output:**

```
['want i pizza', 'i want pizza', 'pizza want i']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hashmap when the key is a word you wish to find and the value is a boolean that says if was found in the sentence or not. 
if one of the words was not found or a word in the sentence does not exist return false; 
other wise its true:

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(scanTheWords("want i pizza") );
    System.out.println(scanTheWords("i want pizza") );
    System.out.println(scanTheWords("i want a pizza on monday") );


}
public static boolean scanTheWords (String sentence)
{
    HashMap<String, Boolean> words = new HashMap<>();
    words.put("i", false);
    words.put("want", false);
    words.put("pizza", false);
    String [] senteceWord = sentence.split(" ");

    for(String s: senteceWord)
    {
        if(!words.containsKey(s))
            return false;
        else 
            words.put(s, true);
    }
    for ( boolean b : words.values())
    {
        if(b==false)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Output

true
true
false

Answer (score 0):

Using python with set:

```
query = "i want a pizza".split()

l = ["want i pizza", "i want pizza", "pizza want i", "i want a pizza on monday"]`

l = [x.split() for x in l]

print([x for x in l if set(x) - set(query)==set() ])
```

**Output:**

```
[['want', 'i', 'pizza'], ['i', 'want', 'pizza'], ['pizza', 'want', 'i']]
```